# What can I do with OpenSocial in terms of building 3rd party apps?

Tags: opensocial

I have read the `Open Social` blog and am trying to build an app for one of the third parties that uses the Open Social model for their applications.

And I'm still not clear what it enables me to do with our application, could someone provide an `OpenSocial for Dummies` breakdown?

Here are my questions:

- Does it allow me to use the hosting web-site's login as authentication and sessionization for my web application (e.g., once someone has logged into the third-party, they are automatically authenticated for mine if it's built on OpenSocial?
- Does it allow for web service call to say grab selective information about that person's network?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the question still relevant? Maybe you should consider removing it?